# How can I draw a Polyline (in WPF) without anti-aliasing?

Tags: wpf, graphics

I am trying to draw a *polyline* without anti-aliasing.

I think the answer may have something to do with setting the EdgeMode, but I've tried on various elements and cannot get a good result:

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(???, EdgeMode.Aliased)
```

Let's start from the ground up, because it seems like there are potentially a few places where something needs to be changed.

The *polyline* is drawn onto a *StreamGeometry*:

```
using (StreamGeometryContext gc = virtGeom.Open())
{
    gc.BeginFigure(firstPoint, false, false);
    gc.PolyLineTo(virtPoints, true, true);
}
```

That is then drawn into the *DrawingContext* of a *DrawingVisual*, which is eventually rendered to a *RenderTargetBitmap* which serves as the source for an *Image*.

Any ideas appreciated!

A complete example, that demonstrates the antialiasing, is shown below. This does *not* include any attempt to resolve it as various attempts to use SetEdgeMode produced no improvement.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Antialias.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Antialias"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="400" Background="#FFCFCFCF" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="Img" Width="320" Height="320"/>
        <Image x:Name="Img2" Width="320" Height="320" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Antialias
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            int w = (int)Img.Width;
            int h = (int)Img.Height;

            // Create RenderTargetBitmap and assign as image source
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            Img.Source = rtb;

            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            StreamGeometry geom = new StreamGeometry();
            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 20)
            {
                StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round
            };

            // Draw a simple line from top left to bottom right
            Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>()
            {
                new Point(w, h)
            };
            using (StreamGeometryContext gc = geom.Open())
            {
                gc.BeginFigure(startPoint, false, false);
                gc.PolyLineTo(points, true, true);
            }

            // Apply white background and then draw geometry
            using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, w, h));
                dc.DrawGeometry(null, pen, geom);
            }

            // Render to RTB
            rtb.Render(dv);

            // Part 2: Cut a clip (20 x 20) from the rendered bitmap and zoom in (using NearestNeighbor)
            CroppedBitmap cbmp = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(Img2, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);

            // Apply the zoomed sampled to the second image
            Img2.Source = cbmp;

            // Look for antialiasing (pixels part way between red and not white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you use a DrawingImage instead of a DrawingVisual and a RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: Please do post an [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Clemens Possibly because I don't know any better. It's all kind of new to me, so I'm just figuring it out as I go.

Comment: So why are you doing all this StreamGeometry and DrawingVisual stuff at all when you could just add a Polyline element to a Canvas and you're done?

Comment: @Rekshino Added example.

Comment: @Clemens Drawing is being done to a virtual image, with all sorts of image manipulation being done. It's not as simple as just "add a Polyline element to a Canvas".

Answer (score 1):

The obvious candidate for having the *EdgeMode* set to *Aliased* is the **DrawingVisual**, but setting it seemed to make no difference:

```
    // This had no effect!
    RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(dv, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

**DrawingVisual** has a protected property *VisualEdgeMode*, which presumably should have been set by calling the above. During debugging, I put a watch on the property and found it was ***not being set!***

As it's a protected property you cannot set it directly, but you can create a subclass and do it that way. In the end, this is what worked for me:

```
    class DrawingVisualAliased : DrawingVisual
    {
        public DrawingVisualAliased() : base()
        {
            VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is the best way. It seems like the property should be set by calling *RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode*, so maybe there's something else not quite right.

Thanks to @Rekshino for pushing me to create an example. It certainly helped to be able to work on a very simplified version of the problem, with a clear visual representation of it.